# Jquery append dropdown won't show values [Laravel 5]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Fellow coders,

I'm running against a small wall here. I am currently realising a project for my internship company, what I have to do is make an hour registration app in the CRM they have here.

My question is: How can I Use the value I received in PHP to dropdown in the Jquery dropdown field. (the reason why I want this is because the user has to fill in the title of the project and the task: project - taskname kinda deal. The 2 values are being shown in my PHP. But when I try to use it in my Jquery yo append the dropdown it doesn't show any values besides an empty dropdown box

```
   $("#addField").click(function (){
      var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
      project_id = $('#project_id').val();
      note = $('#note').val();
      date = $('#date').val();
      hours = $('#hours').val();
      var markup = "<tr id='addRow-"+(addRows)+"'><td hidden>{{  $user_id->first_name }}</td></td>"
      + user_id + 
      " <td> <select class='project_id' value='{!! \App\Project::getCompanyName($hoursregistration->project_id) !!} - {!! \App\Subproject::getTaskTitle($hoursregistration->subproject_id)!!}'></td>"
      + project_id +
      "<td><input type='text' value='{{ $hoursregistration->note }}' name='note' class='note'></td></td>"
      + note +   
      "<td><input type='date' class='date' value='{!! \App\Helpers::dateFormat($hoursregistration->date) !!}'></td>"
      + date +
      "<td><input type='hours' class='hours' value='{{ $hoursregistration->hours }}'></td></td>"
      + hours +
      "<td><button id='btn-save' name='btn-save' class='btn btn-default btn-xd btn-save save-hoursregistration' value='' rel='addRow-"+addRows+"'>Save</button>"
      $("table tbody").append(markup);
```

This is the Jquery function I wrote that appends a new row to the time table.

```
 <tbody id="content">
                @foreach ($hoursregistrations as $hoursregistration)
                <tr>
                   <td id="user_id" hidden>{{  $user_id->first_name }}</td>
                   <td id="project_id subproject_id">{!! App\Project::getCompanyName($hoursregistration->project_id) !!} - {!! \App\Subproject::getTaskTitle($hoursregistration->subproject_id)!!}</td>      
                   <td id="note">{!! $hoursregistration->note !!}</td>    
                   <td id="date">{!! \App\Helpers::dateFormat($hoursregistration->date) !!}</td>
                   <td id="hours">{!! $hoursregistration->hours !!}</td>
                   <td>
                    <button id="btn-edit" name="btn-edit" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" value="{{$hoursregistration->id}}">Edit</button>
                    <button id="btn-delete" name="btn-delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete delete-hoursregistration" value="{{ $hoursregistration->id }}">Delete</button>
                    <button id="btn-save" name="btn-save" class="btn btn-default btn-xd btn-save save-hoursregistration" value="">Save</button>
                </td>
```

This is the piece of code I wrote to show the values in the view table of my application.

```
addRows++;

      $(".btn-save").click(function(){

        rowId = $(this).attr('rel');

        var url = '/hoursregistrations/create';
        var data = {
            user_id: {{  $user_id->id }},
            project_id: $("tr#addRow-"+rowId + " .project_id").val(),
            note: $("tr#addRow-"+rowId + "  .note").val(),
            hours: $("tr#addRow-"+rowId + " .hours").val(),
            date: $("tr#addRow-"+rowId +  " .date").val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            headers:{ 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("table tbody").append(markup);
        //redirect
        if(type=="exit")
            window.location = "create.blade.php";
    }
});
```

And this is my Ajax function that redirects to the blade file. And executes the store function within my controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //$hoursregistration= new Hoursregistration($request->except(''));


    $input = Input::all();
   //dd($input);
    $hoursregistration = new Hoursregistration();

    $hoursregistration->user_id = Sentinel::getUser()->id;
    $hoursregistration->project_id = $input['project_id'];
    $hoursregistration->subproject_id = $input['subproject_id'];
    $hoursregistration->date = $input['date'];
    $hoursregistration->note = $input['note'];
    $hoursregistration->hours = $input['hours'];
    $hoursregistration->save();
    return redirect('hoursregistrations')->with('success', Lang::get('message.success.create'));
}
```

This is my controller file.

In conclusion: How can I add {!! App\Project::getCompanyName($hoursregistration->project_id) !!} - {!! \App\Subproject::getTaskTitle($hoursregistration->subproject_id)!!}

inside my Javascript append function so I can use AJAX to post the selected dropdown value into the database.

Apologies in advance for my inability to explain things.

EDIT:

```
<td id="project_id subproject_id">{!! App\Project::getCompanyName($hoursregistration->project_id) !!} - {!! \App\Subproject::getTaskTitle($hoursregistration->subproject_id)!!}</td>
```

This line of code in my loop that displays the rows from the table does not work in the dropdown of my javascript.

```
 <td> <select class='project_id' value='{!! \App\Project::getCompanyName($hoursregistration->project_id) !!} - {!! \App\Subproject::getTaskTitle($hoursregistration->subproject_id)!!}'></td>"
  + project_id +
```

Comment: Really not clear what specific probelm is. Note however that ID's can not be duplicated in a page...they are unique by definition. Also likely need to use ***event delegation*** to account for elements that don't exist at the time you add the event listeners

Comment: ID is not duplicated, they are shown and later on used. As far as my understanding goes. The thing I would like to achieve here, is that right now the (note, date and hours) part in Ajax work. But the dropdown that contains subproject and project_id doesn't. When I try to use those values in the javascript append dropdown. It doesn't show anything in the dropdown, resulting in not being able to post the new row to my database using ajax because I get an error that there is no input

Comment: I'll check event delegation out

Comment: ID's are defintiely duplicated ... you have loops creating rows using same id's

Comment: Deleted some of the id's, no clue why I was so blind to see that yeah. I am looping through it all creating id's over and over again. Thanks for that

Comment: but yeah, my question still hasn't been answered

Comment: Still not really clear what problem is and what should set your dropdown values...scale this down to bare minimum [mcve]

Comment: As I stated in the original book I wrote here. The result I would wish to receive it that the company name and the task name to be shown in the dropdown menu created by the javascript. (Company_name - Task_name)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the option tag within the select tag. A.k.a I feel really REALLY stupid rn